# What is a URI parameter for openLDAP that contains a schema, host, and port?

Tags: c++, c, database, ldap, openldap

Specifically "the uri parameter may be a comma- or whitespace-separated list of URIs containing only the schema, the host, and the port fields" what does this mean?

Working with openLDAP in c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple list of URIs. The list can be separated by whitespace or comma:

Example:

`http://myhost.com:4567,http://myhost1.com:45,http://myhost2.com:34545`

or

`http://myhost.com:4567 http://myhost1.com:45 http://myhost2.com:34545`